# Create a doc. if it does not exist in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, transactions

I'm using Mongo 3.2.10 now. I would like to create a document on demand like that:

1. retrieve a document from a collection by id
2. create the doc. if it does not exist

Can I do (1) and (2) *atomically* with Mongo 3.2.10 ?

Comment: `findAndModify` with `upsert` option set to true will do. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you